# Two Frame Layout

Tags: tables, formatting, layout

I want to achieve a document layout which consists of two frames.
The larger frame should extends different content types (sections, tables, figures etc.), the smaller frame only of numbers or normal paragraphes (see picture).

Also it is necessary to summarize the two frames in a new "row".

[image]

What's the way to go to create such a layout?

Comment: Maybe `\marginpar` ?

Comment: @Fran Nah, dosn't work with table.

Comment: Then flowfram, tufte, paracol, marginnote ... without a good MWE  and explain clearly the purpose of this frame and its mandatory requirements and what is open to suggestions, in just a guessing game.

Comment: Yeah, you're right: I want to create an exam layout. The left column should consist of the tasks, the right table column of the points.